# Regular Expression to match a specific URL broken up by arbitrary characters

Tags: regex, django

I run a Django-based forum (the framework is probably not important to the question, but still) and it has been increasingly getting spammed with posts that link to a specific website constantly (www.solidwoodkitchen.co.uk - these people are apparently the worst).

I've implemented a string blocking system that stops them posting to the forum if the URL of the website is included in the post, but as spam bots usually do, it has figured out a way around that by breaking up the URL with other characters (eg. w_w_w.s*olid_wood*kit_ch*en._*co.*uk .). So a couple of questions:

1. Is it even possible to build a regex capable of finding the specific URL within a block of text even when it has been modified like that?
2. If it is, would this cause a performance hit?

Comment: This doesn't seem that elegant, but if it's always a single character you could use `w(?.)?w(?.)?w(?.)?.(?.)?...` and so on.

Comment: Why not just filter out the junk (`filter(lambda x: x not in '_*', input)`) an then proceeed with your current filtering system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

You could break the url into a string of characters, then join them together with `[^a-z0-9]*?`. So in this case with `www.solidwoodkitchen.co.uk` the resulting regex would look like:

```
w[^a-z0-9]*?w[^a-z0-9]*?w[^a-z0-9]*?[.][^a-z0-9]*?s[^a-z0-9]*?o[^a-z0-9]*?l[^a-z0-9]*?i[^a-z0-9]*?d[^a-z0-9]*?w[^a-z0-9]*?o[^a-z0-9]*?o[^a-z0-9]*?d[^a-z0-9]*?k[^a-z0-9]*?i[^a-z0-9]*?t[^a-z0-9]*?c[^a-z0-9]*?h[^a-z0-9]*?e[^a-z0-9]*?n[^a-z0-9]*?[.][^a-z0-9]*?c[^a-z0-9]*?o[^a-z0-9]*?[.][^a-z0-9]*?u[^a-z0-9]*?k
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/-bLffnUeUkWvACe8)

This could would basically search for the entire string of characters seperated by zero or more non alphanumeric characters.

Or you could take the input text and strip out all punctuation then simply search for `wwwsolidwoodkitchencouk`.

Comment: I agree with the last part of the solution:
`'wwwsolidwoodkitchencouk' in re.sub("[^a-z]", "", "visit this link w_w_w.s*olid_wood*kit_ch*en._*co.*uk now".lower())`

Comment: Accepting this for the last paragraph, which is what I'm going to use. Thanks!